# How to create a reset button to uncheck all radio and check buttons?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, tkinter.checkbutton

I am writing a code and I need to create a reset button to uncheck all radio buttons and checkbuttons, i keep on getting this error; AttributeError: 'IntVar' object has no attribute 'delete'

here is the code i used in creating the reset button:

```
def resetbtn():
    var.delete(0, END)
    cv1.delete(0, END)
    cv2.delete(0, END)
    cv3.delete(0, END)
    cv4.delete(0, END)
    cv5.delete(0, END)
    cv6.delete(0, END)
    cv7.delete(0, END)
    entry1.delete(0, END)

btn2= Button(root, text= 'Reset', command= resetbtn)
btn2.grid(row= 10, column=2)


mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `deselect` property like here:

```
from tkinter import *

def resetbtn():
    ch1.deselect()
    ch2.deselect()

root = Tk()

ch1 = Checkbutton(root)
ch1.grid(row=10, column=1)
ch2 = Checkbutton(root)
ch2.grid(row=10, column=2)
btn2 = Button(root, text= 'Reset', command=resetbtn)
btn2.grid(row=10, column=3)

mainloop()
```